# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'com/amazonaws/services/sqs/request.handlers'

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-gradle-plugin

I even tried clean and rebuild my project it builds successfully but when i try to run my app it always throws this error message and I also manually tried to delete my /.gradle folder and re-opened android studio and run my app, then also again it's the same error.In this project I'm just trying to connect my app with AWS Dynamodb.

this is my error :

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'com/amazonaws/services/sqs/request.handlers'
```

this was my gradle :

```
   /* Copyright © 2018 Quillbook. All rights reserved */
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 27
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.dumpcoders.danielcruise.quillbook"
            minSdkVersion 17
            multiDexEnabled true
            targetSdkVersion 27
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }

    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'

                exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
                exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'

    }
}




 dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
        compile('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.7@aar') { transitive = true }
        compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.6.16'
        compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider:2.6.16'
        compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.6.16'
        compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.6.16'
        compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobileanalytics:2.6.16'
        compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.6.16'
        compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-sns:2.6.16'
        compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-sqs:2.6.16'
        implementation files('libs/aws-android-sdk-apigateway-core-2.6.15.jar')
    }
```

this is my current gradle :

```
   /*
 * Copyright © 2018 Quillbook. All rights reserved
 */

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dumpcoders.danielcruise.quillbook"
        minSdkVersion 17
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'

}
dexOptions {

    jumboMode true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"

}
}

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
        implementation ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.15@aar') { transitive = true }
        implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.6.15'
        implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider:2.6.15'
        implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.6.15'
        implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.6.15'
        implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobileanalytics:2.6.15'
        implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.6.15'
        implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-sns:2.6.15'
        implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-sqs:2.6.15'
        api group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-android-sdk-apigateway-core', version: '2.6.15'
    }
```

[This is the screenshot of my "app/libs" folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odVaP.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
implementation files('libs/aws-android-sdk-apigateway-core-2.6.15.jar')
```

with

```
 compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-android-sdk-apigateway-core', version: '2.6.15'
```

if not work,try below command for identify the issue

```
gradlew -q dependencies yourProject:dependencies --configuration compile
```

Comment: Thanks man! @JZM .....but now it throws a different  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Comment: I also tried your other command in the terminal but BUILD FAILED in 1m 43s Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.

Comment: Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead. simply replace compile with implementation keyword for example `compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-android-sdk-apigateway-core', version: '2.6.15'` updated like implementation `group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-android-sdk-apigateway-core', version: '2.6.15'`

Comment: That solved some issues but now this is the Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't write [D:\Quillbook\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\Daniel Cruise\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.amazonaws\aws-android-sdk-apigateway-core\2.6.15\f96d5eab7b1404dd981401b7e3f596e38074adde\aws-android-sdk-apigateway-core-2.6.15.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [aws-android-sdk-apigateway-core-2.6.15.jar:com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/apigateway/annotation/Parameter.class]))

Comment: it clearly state duplicate entry of lib,review it from lib folder if it's there, `implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')` also compile all library from lib folder

Comment: which lib app/libs ?

Comment: how to compile all library files from app/libs folder?